# What is a convention base delegate in the context of lazy loading in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, conventions

What is a convention base delegate in the context of lazy loading in EF Core?

I am learning the EF Core over [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading) and I come across the following excerpt:

> The ILazyLoader interface represents a component that is responsible for loading navigation properties if they haven't already been loaded. This approach circumvents the generation of proxies which isn't supported on all platforms. ILazyLoader can be used in one of two ways. It can be injected into the principal entity in the relationship, where it is used to load dependants. This requires that your model class(es) take a dependency on Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure, which is available in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions package. **Or you can use a convention-based delegate.**

While I understand well the dependency injection solution I still do not understand what exactly is referred to by the **Or you can use a convention-based delegate.**. So, if it is clear for someone what is referred to in the excerpt, could you, please, share a link to a more profound documentation on the matter or describe the idea in a nutshell?

Comment: It's talking about this [lazy loading without proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading-without-proxies). You'd define the LazyLoader as a delegate purely to circumvent adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions` package as a dependency in your classes.

Comment: @Dennis1679, what should be the body for such a delegate and where should it be defined? Also, it is not clear for me how can we get a type from the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions` package without adding the package as a dependency?